# Вопрос по MIGX ModX (посчитать сумму всех полей)

Tags: modx, migx

Собственно нужно посчитать значения полей и вывести в другое поле. Как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

Только с помощью сниппета. Вот так можно получить значение тв по имени и айдишнику ресурса

```
    $tvname = 'tv_name';
    $docid= 'resource_id';
    $tv = $modx->getObject('modTemplateVar', array('name' => $tvname));
    $outputvalue = $tv->renderOutput($docid);
    $items = $modx->fromJSON($outputvalue);
    print_r($items);
```